# Example of Non-axiomatic theory?

Tags: axioms, peano-axioms

Im fairly sure that non-axiomatic theories exist (in a mathematical logic sense, aka not considering Creationism and all that...), but I cant think of any examples.  Im wondering if I have a theory $T$ which extends First Order Arithmetic and is complete, can that theory be non-axiomatizable?  Since $T$ extends FOA and is complete, it must be inconsistent by Godel's thms, but what does this say about its axiomatization?  I imagine that it can be axiomatic with inconsistent axioms, but is there some way for it to be non-axiomatic as well? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *theory* here? It is usually considered as a set of formulas, but then we can regard all the elements as axioms. Or.. what do you mean by *axiomatizable*? Recursively enumerable axiom system?

Comment: I'm not a mathematician but my understanding is in Math (as opposed to empirical science) a theory is by definition derived from a set of axioms? Otherwise, I think it's called conjecture isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have misunderstood Godel's theorem. By Godel's theorems we know that $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb{N},+,.,0,S)$ is not recursively axiomatizable. But this does not at all imply that it is inconsistent. In fact it is consistent, since the theory has a model, namely $(\mathbb{N},+,.,0,S)$.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much, this is clearing things up for me.  One more question:  How could I show that T is not recursively axiomatizable?  Im trying to look at this knowing only that T is an extenstion of FOA, or Typographical Number Theory(TNT), by which I mean there exists a statement b in T which is not in TNT.  T is complete.  How do we know that T is not recursively axiomatizable?  Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure about TNT but the idea should be the same as follows: If $T$ is an extension of $FOA$ then $Q\subset{T}$ where $Q$ denotes Robinson's $Q$. Hence you can do an argument similar to the one you did to show that $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb{N},+,.,0,1,S)$ is not recursively axiomatizable to show that $T$ is not recursively axiomatizable, (Recall that any r.e. complete theory is recursive)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a hypothesis: a theory extending FOA can be both complete and consistent, if it is not axiomatizable by a *recursively enumerable* set of axioms. (roughly speaking, this includes fintie sets of axioms, as well as infinite sets of axioms so long as there is a "computer" program that can tell whether any given statement is one of the axioms or not)

All theories have axiomatizations: for example, we can take *every theorem of the theory* to be one of the axioms. This is even a useful thing to do, on occasion.